terraform is updating the tag every time plan is run
We have a module for creating EFS storage using terraform,
MODULE
locals {
  common_tags = {
      <<removed for brevity>>
      "**kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}"     = "owned"**
      "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/${var.cluster_name}" = "owned"
      "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled"             = "TRUE"
  }
}

#############################################################
## EFS  Security Group ##
#############################################################
## Create EFS Security Group
resource "aws_security_group" "efs_sg_th" {
  name        = var.efs_sg_th_name
  description = "efs security group for all cluster subnets"
  vpc_id      = var.vpcid

  ingress {
    cidr_blocks     = var.subnet_range
    from_port       = 2049
    to_port         = 2049
    protocol        = "tcp"
  }

  egress {
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
  }
    tags = merge (
    local.common_tags,
    {
      Name = var.efs_sg_th_name 
    }
  )

}

data "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
  count = length(var.app_subnetids_private)
  id    = var.app_subnetids_private[count.index]
}

##################### Encryption #######################
/*data "aws_kms_alias" "ext_id" {
  name = var.kms_key_alias
}*/

##################### EFS STORAGE #######################
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs" {
  depends_on       =[ aws_security_group.efs_sg_th ]
  creation_token   = "${var.efs_creation_token}-EFS"
  performance_mode = var.efs_performance_mode 
  throughput_mode  = var.efs_throughput_mode 
  encrypted        = var.efs_encrypted 
  #kms_key_id       = data.aws_kms_alias.ext_id.target_key_arn
  kms_key_id       = var.kms_key_arn
    
  tags = merge (
    local.common_tags,
    {
      Name = var.efs_name
    }
      )
  
  # lifecycle {
  #   ignore_changes = [
  #     # Ignore changes to 
  #     number_of_mount_targets,
  #   ]
  # }
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt" {
  count           = length(var.app_subnetids_private)
  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
  subnet_id       = element(var.app_subnetids_private, count.index)
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.efs_sg_th.id]
}

variable "cluster_name" {
  type = string
}

root main.tf
module "EFS-with-thales-key" {
  depends_on            = [module.eksCluster, module.eksBootstrap]
  source                = "../modules/efsCSIDriver/clusterEFS-thales"
  env                   = var.env
  cluster_name          = var.cluster_name
  efs_sg_th_name        = "app323-efs-thales-sg"
  vpcid                 = var.vpcid
  subnet_range          = ["x.x.x.x/x"]
  app_subnetids_private = var.app_subnetids_private
  efs_creation_token    = "app323-prod-thales"
  efs_performance_mode  = "generalPurpose"
  efs_throughput_mode   = "bursting"
  efs_encrypted         = true
  kms_key_arn           = var.thales_kms_arn
  efs_name              = "app323_efs_prod_thales"
}

variable "cluster_name" {
  type = string
}

terraform.tfvars
cluster_name            = "app323-prod-cluster"

After every plan execution, following occurs in the plan
# **module.EFS-with-thales-key.aws_efs_file_system.efs will be updated in-place**
  ~ resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs" {
        id                              = "fs-0883a481ffxxxxx"
      ~ tags                            = {
          + "kubernetes.io/cluster/app323-prod-cluster"     = "owned"
            # (12 unchanged elements hidden)
        }
        # (12 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
  # **module.EFS-with-thales-key.aws_security_group.efs_sg_th will be updated in-place**
  ~ resource "aws_security_group" "efs_sg_th" {
        id                     = "sg-0c7ab808d0bxxxxx"
        name                   = "app323-efs-thales-sg"
      ~ tags                   = {
          + "kubernetes.io/cluster/app323-prod-cluster"     = "owned"

I am not able to figure out why this particular tag is getting updated everytime. There are no changes being made to cluster_name variable.
I checked the code and all seems fine to me.
There are two tags in the local.common_tags block that uses cluster_name as placeholder/variable but only one out of them is getting updated everytime.
I am not able to figure out the logic behind. If there is problem in using placeholder $variable_name, then both tags should get updated.

Do you think there is any kind of out of ban process in your environments(s) that could modify tags?

Which AWS provider version are you using? Does the var.cluster_name value change? Are there multiple environments? How are you dealing with the terraform state?

@RossBush No there are no such processes.

@MarkoE "terraform_version": "1.1.5"
var.cluster_name value doesn't change. It is defined in terraform.tfvars and it doesn't change. And this variable is used by multiple modules though. For eg. EKS Cluster.
We have different branches in gitlab for different environments. So environment doesn't change.
We used remote backend S3 to store terraform state file.

Ok, what is the AWS provider version?

providers.tf doesn't mention anything about AWS provider version but I can see the following when I run a plan,

Installing hashicorp/aws v3.72.0...
Installed hashicorp/aws v3.72.0 (signed by HashiCorp)


Can you check if this tag is set in the state file and on EFS?

@Filip No it isn't there. Another tags is there which also uses variable cluster_name as a placeholder but not the one i have reported above,

@Filip so every time it is showing up in the plan because it is not set in the state file already. Understood. But what could be the reason for this, any idea?
